# Expanding and retracting div using js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Im having trouble with a function Im trying to run for a website. What I am trying to do is move and then expand a div on a button click. After the click, the text in the button changes to "close". When the close button is clicked, the div goes back to its original position.

For the life of me I cant figure out how to make it work.

Here is what I have so far

```
           <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 

var text = 1;

$('button').click(function(){
    if(text == 1){
        $("div.div1").toggleClass("animateSlide");
        $('button').html('Go Back');
        text = 0;
    } else{
        $("div.div1").toggleClass("animateSlide");
        $('button').html('Start Animation');
        text = 1;
    }
});
    </script> 
    </head>
    <body>





   <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="col-xs-12 v-center">
        <div class="content text-center">

            <div class="col-xs-4 animated slideInRight  ">
                <div class="div1"><button>Start Animation</button></div>


            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-2 animated slideInRight"> <a href="#">       hello</a>


            </div>
             <div class="col-xs-2 animated slideInRight"><p>hello</p>

            </div>

        </div>
      </div>


      <style>
.div1{
    transition: all .5s;
    background:#98bf21;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
}

.animateSlide{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    opacity: .5;
    margin-left:100px;
}</style>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle..

Comment: http://jsbin.com/fudotiyogu/edit?html,output

Comment: That is what is happening with my code right now. I need the box to stay expanded after the first click, then shrink back after it gets clicked again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate class and use `.toggleClass()`

```js
var text = 1;

$('button').click(function(){
    if(text == 1){
        $('div').toggleClass('animated');
        $('button').html('Go Back');
        text = 0;
    } else{
        $('div').toggleClass('animated');
        $('button').html('Start Animation');
        text = 1;
    }
});
```

```css
div{
    transition: all .5s;
    background:#98bf21;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
}

.animated{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    opacity: .5;
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div><button>Start Animation</button></div>
```

Comment: You are a life saver! Thank you very much!

Comment: How I get the button to change its text on click

Comment: I updated my code to change the button on click. I used a toggle variable named 'text' and the function check the toggle and changes the text each time.

Comment: Thank you, I actually had one last question, if i were to to change div to a class with the name div1 , what would i have to change?

Comment: Ive updated the code, Im having difficulty integrating what you've shown

Answer (score 1):

Pass the second animation function to the callback variable of the first function.

([Demo](http://jsbin.com/fudotiyogu/edit?html,output))

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var c=0;
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({
            left: ++c%2*100 ,
            opacity: '0.5',
            height: '150px',
            width: '150px'
        },'fast', function() {
            $(this).animate({
                width: "100px",
                height: "100px"
            }, 500);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I need it to stay expanded for the first click.

Comment: I need the box to stay expanded once clicked, not shrink back to its original size. When its clicked the second time is when the div should shrink back to its original size